# SyncFusion DataGrid column selection

Tags: reactjs, syncfusion, ej2-syncfusion

I use the DataGrid from SyncFusion for React. They have a selection mode for columns but I can't find a way to get the name of the selected column. Do they have a method that returns the selected column? Something like their getSelectedRecords() method? Or I need to find a way to do it myself?

I tried using their getSelectedRecords() method, but that only returns object of a selected row, doesn't even return the selected cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain the field names of the selected columns, you should begin by retrieving the unique identifiers (UIDs) of the selected columns using the “**getSelectedColumnsUid**“ method. This method returns a string array that contains a list of UIDs for the selected columns. You can then utilize these UIDs to retrieve the corresponding column by utilizing the “**getColumnByUid**“ method. Once you have the column, you can access the field name using the "**field**" property. Below is a code snippet that demonstrates how to list the field names of the selected columns:

```
[index.js]

function DataGrid() {
let grid;
 
  function getSelectedColumnNames() {
    return grid
      .getSelectedColumnsUid()
      .map((uid) => grid.getColumnByUid(uid).field);
  }
 
  function btnClick() {
    console.log(getSelectedColumnNames());
  }
 
  return (
    <div className="control-pane">
      <div className="control-section">
        <button className="e-btn e-primary" onClick={btnClick}>
          Get Selected Column Names
        </button>
        <GridComponent
          ref={(g) => (grid = g)}
          dataSource={data}
          allowPaging={true}
          selectionSettings={{
            allowColumnSelection: true,
            type: 'Multiple',
          }}
        >
      .  .  .  .  .
```

Sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-grid-column-selection

APIs:

1. **getSelectedColumnsUid**: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/api/grid/#getselectedcolumnsuid
2. **getColumnByUid**: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/api/grid/#getcolumnbyuid